# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling

Hi I am learning Angular and trying to follow the Note Mates tutorial on YouTube and I am almost done but this thing is not working for me. I am supposed to make sorting by relevancy and I have this code here and I am getting Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'Object' error for `noteCountObj[noteId]`.

```
sortByRelevancy(searchResults: Note[]) {
    // This method will calculate the relevancy of a note based on the number of times it appears in
    // the search results

    let noteCountObj: Object = {}; // format - key:value => NoteId:number (note object id : count)

    searchResults.forEach(note => {
        let noteId = this.service.getId(note);

        if (noteCountObj[noteId]) {
            noteCountObj[noteId] += 1;
        } else {
            noteCountObj[noteId] = 1;
        }
    });

    this.filteredNotes = this.filteredNotes.sort((a: Note, b: Note) => {
        let aId = this.service.getId(a);
        let bId = this.service.getId(b);

        let aCount = noteCountObj[aId];
        let bCount = noteCountObj[bId];

        return bCount - aCount;
    });
}
```

How can I make this work?
Thank you for the help.

Comment: What is the type of ```noteId```? Is this string or number?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have `strict: true` in your `tsconfig.json` (which is nevertheless a good thing to have). However having this will make the compiler tell you that you have to really "type all the things (properly)"!

<sub>It's actually the compiler option `noImplicitAny` that's set to `true`, but most likely you have `strict: true` in your config. But the latter option enables a lot of smaller options which makes the typing more strict</sub>

In your case you just used `Object` as type for your `noteCountObj`, while in fact it's something more specific. Try the following typing for your `noteCountObj`:

```
const noteCountObj: Record<number, number> = {};
```

The [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) is a convenient utility function from typescript:

> Constructs an object type whose property keys are Keys and whose property values are Type. This utility can be used to map the properties of a type to another type.

Another way to type this is:

```js
const noteCountObj: {[noteId: number]: number} = {};
```

This could be the more descriptive solution in your case, where the term `noteId` is arbitrarily chosen. It could be anything you want there.

---

If you think you will be using this object type more often, you can extract it from the code, place it in a separate model file and do the following:

```js
export type IdCounter =  {[id: number]: number};
```

You can then import and use this type:

```js
import type { IdCounter } from '../path/to/id-counter.model';

const noteCountObj: IdCounter = {};
```